# How to change ControlMode of SharePoint:FormField control on postback (it changes only after the second postback)

Tags: 2013, aspx, field-controls, aspnet-lifecycle

I have a control in my ASPX file and a button to do postback:

```
<SharePoint:FormField ID="MyID" runat="server" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="Edit"/>
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Postback" OnClick="Button_Clicked"/>
```

In my code-behind I want to change ControlMode of MyID control on postback. But it doesn't work. I do this change using simple piece of code.

```
 MyID.ControlMode=SPControlMode.Display;
```

**However, for some reasons it changes appearance only after the second postback.**

I tried to use debugger and could see that ControlMode of my control changes immediately as expected and I could see that it equals "Display" on SaveViewState and RenderControl events, but anyway I could see my control in Edit mode in the browser.

I ran out of ideas and could not understand what can I do for further investigation. Possibly when I add control through ASPX page I should change it in some special lifecycle event.

**Could you help me in my investigation, please.
Every suggestions are very appreciated.**

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue now. Try to move your code:

```
 MyID.ControlMode=SPControlMode.Display;
```

to `OnInit` or `OnLoad` event. Page_Load is too far in page live cycle when controls in FormField are already rendered.